# Delphi Firemonkey 2 .color property

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

I don't know if it is just me missing something, but I am quite frustrated by this issue.
When I try to set the `.color` property there are no values available such as `claBlue`.

For example:

```
 Canvas.Stroke.Color := claBue.
```

Am I missing a reference?  I have included `FMX.Types`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include into uses unit System.UIConsts and you will get all available color names.

```
uses System.UIConsts;
```

Comment: Accept the answer if this solution suits you.